# find string filter the systeminfo output

Tags: windows, findstr

Use findstr to filter a string  `OS Version`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>systeminfo | findstr  "OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.5, 2020/11/2
```

Notice: `systeminfo | findstr  "OS Version:"` has the same result.
Why the output can't be as below:

```
OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
```

Why the output contains many other lines unrelated to the matching string `OS Version`?

Answer (score 0):

Because "OS Version" matches both "OS" and "Version".  If you want to match the entire string `"OS Version"` instead of either word, this is what you want:

`systeminfo | findstr "OS\ Version"`

And that will match "OS Version" and "BIOS Version" lines.  So filter out the BIO version thing like this:

`systeminfo | findstr "OS\ Version" | findstr /v BIOS`